# spring batch with annotations

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-annotations

I'm currently trying to create a batch with the spring annotations but the batch is never called. No error occurs, my batch isn't called. Its a simple batch that retrieves values from the database and add messages in a queue (rabbitmq).

The main configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchInfrastructureConfiguration {

@Bean
public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}   

public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
    MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setTransactionManager(new ResourcelessTransactionManager());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return  (JobRepository) factory.getObject();
}
}
```

The configuration class specific to my batch

```
@Configuration
@Import(BatchInfrastructureConfiguration.class)
public class PurchaseStatusBatchConfiguration {

@Inject
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilders;

@Inject
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilders;

@Bean
public Job purchaseStatusJob(){
    return jobBuilders.get("purchaseStatusJob")
            .start(step())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step(){
    return stepBuilders.get("purchaseStatusStep")
            .tasklet(new PurchaseStatusBatch())
            .build();
}
}
```

The batch class:

```
public class PurchaseStatusBatch implements Tasklet {

@Inject
private PurchaseRepository  purchaseRepository;

@Inject
@Qualifier(ApplicationConst.BEAN_QUALIFIER_PURCHASE_QUEUE)
private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext)         throws Exception {

    PurchaseDto purchaseDto;
    PurchaseMessage purchaseMessage;

    List<Purchase> notVerifiedPurchase = purchaseRepository.findByVerified(false);
    for (Purchase purchase : notVerifiedPurchase) {
        purchaseDto = new PurchaseDto();
        purchaseDto.setOrderId(purchase.getOrderId());
        purchaseDto.setProductId(purchase.getProductId());
        purchaseDto.setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken());
        purchaseDto.setUserScrapbookKey(purchase.getUserScrapbookKey());
        purchaseMessage = new PurchaseMessage();
        purchaseMessage.setPurchaseDto(purchaseDto);
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(purchaseMessage);
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

The job runner (class calling the batch):

```
@Service
public class PurchaseStatusJobRunner {

@Inject
private JobLocator jobLocator;

@Inject
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

//@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000L)
//@Scheduled(cron="* * * * *") // every 1 minute
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000L)
public void runJob() throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException,        JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException, NoSuchJobException {
    jobLauncher.run(jobLocator.getJob("purchaseStatusJob"), new JobParameters());

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: The problem is that your `PurchaseStatusBatch` instance is not a spring bean... then all its attributes are null (they have not been injected)

Try this :

```
@Bean
public Step step(){
    return stepBuilders.get("purchaseStatusStep")
            .tasklet(purchaseStatusBatch())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public PurchaseStatusBatch purchaseStatusBatch() {
    return new PurchaseStatusBatch()
}
```

When you want to have feedback on your job execution, just use the `JobExecution` instance returned by the `JobLauncher`. You can get the `ExitStatus`, you can get all exceptions catched by the `JobLauncher`, and more information.

Another solution to have feedback would be providing a real database to your JobRepository, and then check execution statuses in it.